# query search from two related tabels using a search term 'q'

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables food  table and restaurants table which are all related by restaurant id

This is the relationship in the food models

```
public function restaurant(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Restaurant');
 }
```

This is the food table

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('food_item');
            $table->integer('restaurant_id');
```

This is the relationship in the restaurants model

```
public function foods(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Food');
}
```

When the user puts input q which is the search term of food item i need it to produce all restaurants which food item according to the search term

Here is the query i wrote but returns 0 results when i do return   json_encode($foodsAll);

```
 public function search(Request $request){
        $foodsAll = Restaurant::whereHas('foods',function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('food_item','like','%'.$request->q.'%');
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing get().

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $foodsAll = Restaurant::whereHas('foods',function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('food_item','like','%'.$request->q.'%');
        })->get();
    }
```